# Condition on checked property of checkbox in html

Tags: angularjs, html, checkbox

How can I put condition on checked property of checkbox?

I have checkboxes for each row in my application. In my database, I have a column 'IsSaved' whose value is either 0 or 1. If IsSaved for a row is 1 then checkbox should automatically be shown as selected.

Here's my code snippet:

```
<td style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="${ID}" ng-checked="${IsSaved} ? true : false" />              
</td>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is that `${IsSaved}` syntax coming from some server-side templating? In that case you dont really need ng-checked, a simple `<input type="checkbox" ${IsSaved ? "checked" : ""} /> ` will do, assuming it can contain expressions.

Comment: Yes, ${IsSaved} is from server side only. I did this but it's showing an error.     <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="${ID}" ${IsSaved ? checked : ""} />

Comment: Please update the question with details on what server side templating you are using, I'm only guessing on what syntax has to be used here. You forgot the quotation marks around "checked" in that try though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access variables of your scope directly by calling it by its variable name: `IsSaved`.

You are using a `ternary expression`, this however is not supported as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#no-control-flow-statements).

Now you can use a shorter expression for this: `IsSaved == 1`, which just results in a truthy or falsy result.

So you get

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select" id="{{ID}}" ng-checked="IsSaved == 1" />
```

*Note: that `ID` variable can be accessed in the scope by the double braces.*

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d3d05ek/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select" value="ID" ng-checked="(IsSaved) ? true : false" />
```

I'm assuming that `IsSaved` is a `$scope` variable in your controller that has scope over your HTML template

This should work

Comment: Sorry. It's not working. IsSaved is the column name. If IsSaved value is 1 then checkbox should be selected.

Comment: Have added the part about `IsScope` being a variable in your `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Siddharath Please try the bellow. This this work for me.

`<td style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="{{ID}}" ng-checked="{{IsSaved}}" />
</td>`

Answer (score -1):

<input name="gender"  checked={id && (user.gender == "Female")}
value="Female" />

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).